# Cut a corner on my box container using CSS

Tags: html, css

**This is what I want to achieve:**

I'm looking to "cut" the lower left corner of the content in the code below
(similar to if you had folded the corner of a page down)
I'd like to know if there is any adjustments I could do to the CSS below to achieve this.

```css
.model-properties {
  padding: 0.8em 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 15%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  color: #c6d2db;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #182229, #182229, #293741, #293741);
  max-height: 700px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<div id="model-properties-container" class="model-properties">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.model-properties:before,
.model-properties:after
{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.model-properties:after {
    border-color: #88b7d5;
    border-left-color: white;
    border-bottom-color: white;
    border-width: 30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e46xvp3x/3/

Comment: Amazing! Is there any way I can make the edge transparent? (the trianlge that is outside the "folded" piece)

Comment: I cant seem to find it. Did you add transparency or opacity? :)

Comment: I have added a div called bottom, and added to css to that div instead. A border-color is changed to opacity.